# Require.js looking in the wrong path for the nested dependencies

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I use WebJars to manage my JavaScript dependencies which means that most of the libraries I use are outside the Require.js base path. The config is created automatically and it works for most libraries. I only have problems with those libraries that call `require()` to load some inner dependencies (usually just external files) - for example [when.js](https://github.com/cujojs/when).

This is the require.js config generated for **when** library:

```
requirejs.config({"paths":{"when":["/webjars/when-node/3.5.2/when","when"]}});
```

This file loads properly. But the problem is that it tries to load further files:

```
...
var timed = require('./lib/decorators/timed');
var array = require('./lib/decorators/array');
var flow = require('./lib/decorators/flow');
var fold = require('./lib/decorators/fold');
...
```

I would expect require.js to use the location of `when.js` to determine the correct locations of the other required files, i. e.:

```
/webjars/when-node/3.5.2/lib/decorators/timed.js
```

But unfortunately require.js uses instead the location of the `main.js` file as the base path which obviously results in a lot of 404 errors and the application crashes.

How can I tell require.js to look in the correct subdirectory?

Answer (score 4):

So according to the RequireJS documentation this seems to be the correct behavior. Unlike CommonJS, every `require()` call is resolved using the base path (it is relative to the base path, not to the location of the file it is called in).

The only way to get around this (as far as I know) is to configure the dependency as a package. The package location is then used for path resolution instead of the general base path. For the mentioned `when` package, the configuration should look something like this:

```
requirejs.config({
  packages: [
    { name: 'when', location: '/path/to/when', main: 'when' }
  ]
});
```

To fix this problem automatically for all my current or future dependencies, I've replaced the [Scala Play Framework loading script](http://www.webjars.org/documentation) with my own solution which loads all WebJars as separate packages.

```
var require = {
    callback : function () {
        var packages = [];
        var shim = {};

        [
            @for(webJarJson <- org.webjars.RequireJS.getSetupJson(routes.WebJarAssets.at("").url).values()) {
                @Html(webJarJson.toString),
            }
        ].forEach(function (webjar) {
            if (webjar.paths) {
                for (var name in webjar.paths) {
                    if (webjar.paths.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                        packages.push({
                            name: name,
                            location: webjar.paths[name][0].replace(/\/[^\/]+$/, ""),
                            main: webjar.paths[name][1]
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            if (webjar.shim) {
                for (var name in webjar.shim) {
                    if (webjar.shim.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                        shim[name] = webjar.shim[name];
                    }
                }
            }
        });             

        requirejs.config({
            packages: packages,
            shim: shim
        });
    }
}
```